# c++ i need an Interpretation

Tags: c++

Sorry but I just need an interpretation of a Boolean call return from a function, I feel quite disappointed with myself having to ask this. its a very simple program but the return has no if,true and im guessing. I have put the questions in the program, could some someone just explain what is going on. Thanks in advance.

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        //check if prime, if it is print it

        if (isPrime(i)) //does this say - if returns true, print?
        {
            cout << i << endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int num)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < num; i++)
    {
        if ( isDivisible(num, i) ) { // not sure about this?
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool isDivisible(int number, int divisor)
{
    return number % divisor == 0; // is this saying return true (if) num    %    div == 0 ?
}
```

Comment: Answer to both questions is yes.

Comment: `if (x)` is equivalent to `if (x == true)`. The shorter version is generally considered better style.

Comment: @AlanStokes I'd tend to say that `if(x)` is equivalent to `if (x!=false)`

Comment: @Christophe Neither is strictly true, but both give roughly the right mental model. I prefer to limit the number of negations; they make my head hurt.

Comment: "not sure about this?" isn't a real question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a comparison, because if you compare some boolean `b` with `true`, the result is the value of `b`.

The test `if (isPrime(i))` says "if `i` is prime".
You could of course rewrite it as the more complex `if (isPrime(i) == true)` — "if it is true that `i` is prime" — but why complicate things?

Similarly, `if(isDivisible(num,i))` means "if `num` is divisible by `i`", and while "if it is true that `num` is divisible by `i`" means the same thing, it's just unnecessary.

Lastly, in `isDivisible`, the value of the comparison `number % divisor == 0` is either `true` or `false`.
The function returns the result of that comparison.